# Мне нужно нарисовать результат обработки Canny поверх оригинального изображения

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Вот рабочий код без Qt, который решает мою задачу:

```
Mat image;
image = imread("C:\\mel.bmp",1);


Mat gray, edqes, out;
cvtColor(image, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Canny(gray, edqes, 50, 150, 3);
cvtColor(edqes, edqes, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
bitwise_or(edqes,image,out);


cvNamedWindow("original",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvNamedWindow("binary",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvNamedWindow("canny",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvNamedWindow("out",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

imshow("original",image);
imshow("binary", gray);
imshow("canny", edqes);
imshow("out", out);
```

Я собираюсь использовать его с Qt, чтобы отобразить на QGraphicsView. Вот этот код я для этого использую:

```
QImage temp = nPixDst->pixmap().toImage();

cv::Mat image = QImage2Mat(temp) ;

int niz = ui->lin_bot->text().toInt();
int verh = ui->lin_top->text().toInt();

Mat gray, edqes, out;
cvtColor(image, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Canny(gray, edqes, niz, verh, 3);
cvtColor(edqes, edqes, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
bitwise_or(edqes,image,out);

nPixDst->setPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage( Mat2QImage( out )) );
```

но я получаю следующую ошибку:

> OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
> OpenCV(3.4.9) Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The
> operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size
> and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in
> cv::binary_op, file
> E:\soft\build\opencv\opencv-src\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp, line 229

как это можно исправить?

вот этот код я использую для конвертирования из QImage в Mat и обратно:

```
QImage MainWindow::Mat2QImage(cv::Mat const& src)
{
    switch(src.type())
    {
    case CV_8UC4:
    {
        cv::Mat view(src);
        QImage view2(view.data, view.cols, view.rows, view.step[0], QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        return view2.copy();
        break;
    }
    case CV_8UC3:
    {
        cv::Mat mat;
        cvtColor(src, mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA); //COLOR_BGR2RGB doesn't behave so use RGBA
        QImage view(mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step[0], QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        return view.copy();
        break;
    }
    case CV_8UC1:
    {
        cv::Mat mat;
        cvtColor(src, mat, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
        QImage view(mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step[0], QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        return view.copy();
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        //throw invalid_argument("Image format not supported");
        return QImage();
        break;
    }
    }
}

cv::Mat MainWindow::QImage2Mat(QImage const& src)
{
    switch(src.format()) {
    case QImage::Format_Invalid:
    {
        cv::Mat empty ;
        return empty  ;
        break;
    }
    case QImage::Format_RGB32:
    {
        cv::Mat view(src.height(),src.width(),CV_8UC4,(void *)src.constBits(),src.bytesPerLine()) ;
        return view ;
        break;
    }
    case QImage::Format_RGB888:
    {
        cv::Mat out ;
        cv::Mat view(src.height(),src.width(),CV_8UC3,(void *)src.constBits(),src.bytesPerLine());
        cv::cvtColor(view, out, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
        return out ;
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        QImage conv = src.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        cv::Mat view(conv.height(),conv.width(),CV_8UC4,(void *)conv.constBits(),conv.bytesPerLine());
        return view ;
        break;
    }
    }
}
```